# Quiero encerrar una operación que invierta mucho tiempo en su ejecución en una promesa, pero no lo consigo

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código:

```
<body>
<p id="loader"></p>
<script>
    (main=()=>{
        let p=document.querySelector('p')
        p.innerText='Loading...'
        OperacionLarga().then(r=>p.innerText='Loaded');
    })()

    function OperacionLarga(){
        return new Promise((r,r2)=>{
            for(let i=0;i<1e6;i++) console.log(i);
            r();
        })
    }
</script>
```

Genero una función a la que llamo "OperacionLarga" que simula la ejecución de una operación que invierte bastante tiempo. Sencillamente es un bucle que itera un millón de veces y lo saca por consola. Antes de llamar a esta función cambio el contenido de párrafo "loader" a "Loading..." y una vez resuelta la promesa lo vuelvo a cambiar a "Loaded", sin embargo no funciona.

Si en vez devolver la promesa con ese código, devuelvo esto:

```
return new Promise(r=>setTimeOut(r,3000))
```

Funciona correctamente. El tema es que yo no quiero hacer una pausa con un tiempo determinado por mí, sino que el tiempo se fije por la duración del algoritmo que contenga la promesa, que en este caso es un bucle. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Hay obligatoriamente que hacer una pausa con un setTimeOut para obtener el resultado que busco?

Comment: Si añades `{}` a una arrow function, debes añadir el `return` explicitamente. Si haces una arrow function como esta: `r=>setTimeOut(r,3000)` sin los corchetes, el return está implícito. El problema es que cuando haces el bucle no le indicas qué es lo que tiene que devolver la promesa... debes añadir el `return` tú mismo! Si no JS no sabe qué línea es la que debe devolver.

Comment: Hola Benito, efectivamente llevas razón, olvidé poner un return en la función flecha, pero aún así no hace lo que yo quiero, pero me da la sensación de que es porque con bucles tan largos el explorador se queda atontao y no refresca la vista. Sino, no encuentro otra explicación.

Comment: @JoséManuel, exactamente ese es el problema. Estás sobrecargando el hilo de ejecución principal y es por eso que el navegador se "congela". Normalmente si va a necesitar realizar procesos largos y pesados, se lo delegas al servidor, no al navegador. Otra opción es usar un `service worker`. [Más info](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/optimize-your-javascript-app-by-using-service-workers/) sobre este último.

Comment: Gracias Marcos, justo esa era la respuesta que estaba esperando.